# parse countInBackground() returning -1

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am taking input from user using the EditText and storing its values in a String variable "d", I am using parse as backend, now on button click I am checking whether "d" is present in table or not using countInBackground method, but "arg0" argument of done() returning -1 even if "d" exist.

Code -

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
                pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                pd.setMessage("Please wait!!");
                pd.show();
                final ParseObject po = new ParseObject("Register");
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery
                        .getQuery("Register");
                query.whereEqualTo("contact", d);
                query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(int arg0, ParseException arg1) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, d + arg0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse is really bad with Count operations. As they say in their documentation:

> Count queries are rate limited to a maximum of 160 requests per minute. They can also return inaccurate results for classes with more than 1,000 objects. Thus, it is preferable to architect your application to avoid this sort of count operation (by using counters, for example.)

I will add that the result can also… never be returned (which probably explain your -1). I had the issue in a afterSave hook with a table of 3k of data, everything was working well, until parse stopped sending a response…

The best way for you would be to write an Cloud Code function on your Register class that will update a counter, as well as a AfterSave hook:

First you can create a new class name `Counter` with 2 fields:

```
+--------+-------+
|  Type  | Name  |
+--------+-------+
| String | name  |
| Number | count |
+--------+-------+
```

Inside you add several rows like this (replace `dx` with the value you need to search in your app):

```
+---------------------+-------+
|        Name         | Value |
+---------------------+-------+
| register_contact_d1 |     0 |
| register_contact_d2 |     0 |
| register_contact_d3 |     0 |
| ...                 |     0 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

Then you need to create the beforeSave Hook to update the counter at the creation of a new object:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Register', function (request, response) {
  var register = request.object;

  if (register.isNew()) {
    var contact = register.get('contact');
    // we increment the counter
    updateContactCounter(contact, 1, function () {
      response.success();
    });
  } else if (register.dirty('contact') && request.master === false) {
     // We block all unwanted modification of contact as we need to be able to decrement its previous value. We check for the masterKey as we gonna use it in the Cloud Code function to update the object
     response.error();
  } else {
     response.success();
  }
});
```

Then we do the Cloud Code function

```
// Takes the Register id as rId, and the new contact value as newValue
Parse.Cloud.define('updateContact', function (request, response) {
    var rId = request.params.rId;
    var newValue = request.params.newValue;

    // We get the object
    var Register = Parse.Object.extend('Register');
    var query = new Parse.Query(Register);
    query.get(rId, {
      success: function(register) {
        // todo handle when oldValue is not set
        var oldValue = register.get('contact');

        // We decrement the old counter
        updateContactCounter(oldValue, -1, function () {
          // We increment the new counter
          updateContactCounter(newValue, 1 function () {
            // we save the new value
            register.set('contact', newValue);
            register.save(null, {
              useMasterKey: true, // we use the masterKey to pass the validation
              success: function () { response.success(); }
              error: function () { response.error(); }
            });
          });
        });
      },

      error: function(object, error) {
        response.error();
      }
    });
});
```

And we finish with the `updateContactCounter` func:

```
function updateContactCounter(contact, value, done) {
    var Counter = Parse.Object.extend('Counter');
    var query = new Parse.Query(Counter);

    // We get the right counter
    query.equalTo('name', 'register_contact_' + contact);
    query.first({
      success: function (obj) {
        obj.increment("count", value);
        obj.save(null, {
           success: function () {
             done();
           }
           error: function () {
             done();
           }
        });
      },
      error: function () {
        done();
      }
    });
}
```

And you should be good…

This code is just so you understand the process, it is definitely *not* perfect nor tested, it is missing important parts (error and undefined values handling), and can can be improved in many ways (you can use promises to execute updateContactCounter in parallel).

Comment: Just added an example about how to handle a counter with parse. If the answer helped you or answered your question, don't forget to mark it as `accepted` :)

Comment: Thankyou for the explaination..... if it was a good question for developers, please vote it up!!!